# Azure environmental variables removing last character ('=') from key giving 'invalid password' when connecting to azure cache for redis

Tags: python, azure, redis

I'm trying to connect to an Azure Redis server for use as a celery queue. I can connect to it just fine from local dev. When I try to start a celery worker via ssh, the broker URL drops the '=' from the end of the password, giving an invalid password error.

However, the celery instance run from the Flask app works fine - I just don't have a worker to complete the task.

I've tried regenerating the keys several times to see if I got one that doesn't end with '='.

I print the connection string and in local dev I get:

```
rediss://:{mykey[-3]}50=@{mysit}.redis.cache.windows.net:6380/
```

and on the Azure app service I get:

```
rediss://:{mykey[-2]}50@{mysit}.redis.cache.windows.net:6380/
```

with missing '=' before the @. I've quadruple checked that the key is correct in the application settings.

The code is identical to the local dev code, which works as intended.

I changed the code loading the string to

```
f"rediss://:{os.environ.get('REDIS_KEY')}=@$mysite$.redis.cache.windows.net:6380/0"
```

and that fixed the problem for the celery worker, but it causes the actual web app to fail a password error. In any case, this seems like a shady and difficult to maintain fix.

Hard coding the connection string solves both problems, but is obviously not a desirable solution.

For some reason, Azure app service is removing the trailing '=' from the environmental variables when I try to run commands from the command line, but not from the variables that the Flask app sees. Reading the code from the environmental variables and printing from ssh using ```printenv`` also shows the '=' as missing both with the virtual environment loaded and without.

How do I get the proper string into the environment so I can start the worker?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can see the length of the key is fixed 44 characters. So my idea is to set a key with a tail of additional fixed length characters like `AAA` into the environment, then to get it by intercept the first 44 characters.

For example, `set REDIS_KEY=QfWOl8KFGuD7Q3PG1rvsD4igwLT5ZxTyIbhvO8TvpX0=AAA`, then to get it in Python.

```
import os
key = os.environ.get('REDIS_KEY')[:44]
# 'QfWOl8KFGuD7Q3PG1rvsD4igwLT5ZxTyIbhvO8TvpX0='
```

Hope it helps.